# Angular 2 router config lazy loaded modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, routes

I'm trying to create a service which uses router configuration to create map of routes based on components. It works fine when you don't use lazy loaded module routes.

But I don't know how to get routes from lazy loaded module. In route object there is just loadChildren string and that's it. I digged little bit into angular2 internals and it is using RouterConfigLoader internally to load lazy loaded routes. But it is not exported from RoutingModule, so I suppose it should not be used from the outside.

Is there any public API which would help me with that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

But that's the whole idea of lazy loaded modules. No reference exists to the lazy loaded module, so it ain't loaded on load (can I use the word load some more?).

Which also means no routing is available. Based on the string, angular2 loads the (entire) module, and injects the routing on the fly. If you want to know the routing beforehand, you should either not use lazy modules, or do it by hand

Comment: Well, I don't necessarily need them to be loaded lazily, but I like the way how are lazy loaded routes specified. I guess it is not possible to keep them specified the same way but load module right away? (I suppose importing that module would also import its routes which is not what I want).

Comment: It's the current implementation But Angular could simply pass the loaded routes to some listener, and always pass the fully assembled routing effective after loading the new module. Let's do a feature request?

Comment: @OndraŽižka any updates? It seems like lazily loaded routes should be merged into `router.config` after they're loaded.